# Checkbox Custom styles not working in Mozilla Firefox browser

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to add custom styles for checkbox, its working fine in both Google Chrome and Safari browser, but it's not working in Mozilla Firefox.
Following are the styles I wrote.

```css
input[type='checkbox'] {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 1px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type='checkbox']:after{
    content: "";
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 13px;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    left: -2;
    top: -2;
    font-size: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #D5D8EC;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

// input[type='checkbox']:hover:after, input[type='checkbox']:checked:hover:after {
//  background: #fff;
//  content: url(../img/tick.png);
//  color: #000;
// }

input[type='checkbox']:checked:after{
    background: #fff;
    content: url(../img/tick.png);
    color: #000;
}
```

Kindly Help me

Comment: Using pseudo elements on elements that have an empty content model is not supposed to work to begin with, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-a-before-or-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field

Comment: The question does not seem to involve php so perhaps that tag could be removed. The only workaround I know is to alter the HTML so if you have control of the HTML and this is permissible perhaps you could add an html tag.

Answer (score 1):

Formally, pseudo elements are not supported on elements such as input. See for example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after

> Note: The pseudo-elements generated by ::before and ::after are
> contained by the element's formatting box, and thus don't apply to
> replaced elements such as , or to 
>  elements.

It seems however that some browsers do allow such pseudo elements in some cases, and in the case of this question Safari and Chrome implement pseudo elements on input elements of type checkbox. Firefox does not and in this regard seems to be following standards more closely.

The question therefore is what to do about it? There are various tricks, one of which is to add a containing element e.g. a span and give that the desired formatting. This of course assumes you have control of the HTML